# Grabbing next character from input stream without storing it

Tags: c++, input

Is it possible to grab the next character from the consol user input stream in C++ without having to store it in a char/string variable? Java has this feature.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? `std::cin.get()` will return a character, you don't have to store it if you don't want to..

Comment: `std::basic_istream::get()` returns a char which can be ignored.

Comment: So you want to [`ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) the input?

Comment: There's no reason to initialize a 256-character array if the input is only 100 characters long.

Comment: I now understand how cin works in C++. It waits for input first because the input buffer is empty, and cin.get(char var) then extracts the first character from the buffer. You can then iteratively call cin.get(char var) until the buffer is empty again.

Comment: Yes, I accept that cin.get() works as well. Thanks for all the responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `peek` just to look at the character without extracting it. Check if [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/peek/) helps.

Comment: Nice. That's what I was looking for. :)

Comment: Glad it helped :) You can accept the answer if you consider it valid.

Comment: Must wait 2 minutes lol. EDIT: Accepted and marked as useful.